# How to display every received frame in WebRTC streaming?

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc, video-streaming, html5-video

I am working on a WebRTC video streaming between a moving drone and a remote device. Sometimes, **the video freezes**. I watched some webrtc's and video's statistics and noticed that during freezes, **some frames were received, but no frame was displayed** on the video.

---

To explain, I compared:

- About of the `video` element, the difference of `webkitdecodedframecount` in the last second
- About the *Inbound Stream* (using `RTCInboundRtpStreamStats`) the difference of `framesReceived` in the last second

During a ~4s freeze where I was recording my screen, 0 frames were *decoded* but about **16** frames were received.

---

So my questions are:

- **Why is there such a difference between received frames and displayed frames ?**
- **How to display received frames instantly ?**

---

**Edit**:

- At the beginning of the *freeze*, 4 packets have been lost.
- At the end of the *freeze*, the stream worked well again, with a lower resolution

Comment: WebRTC will drop late frames. You need to make sure your frames arrive with correct timestamps and arrive individually, not in buckets. If you are using encoders like ffmpeg, it will spit out a bucket of frames (with default encoding and muxing settings), because it's targeted for HLS. You need to make sure your encoder spits out individual frames instantly. Also, your network could be a culprit - for example, high packet loss can lead to frames arriving in bunches.

Comment: Did you found a solution/ workaround to that problem? I have the exact same issue and I was just wondering of how this can be achieved?

Comment: It's is indeed related to packet loss. Unfortunately, I concluded that webrtc is not meant to be used in such a way.. For a real time video streaming from a moving drone, you may get a look into wifi [broadcast] (https://github.com/rodizio1/EZ-WifiBroadcast) for instance.